# How can I show unique date and count() records MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

I have table with following structure and records.

**table t1**

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| name |  f_inserted | timestamp           |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| AAA  |   1         | 2012-04-10 06:44:19 |
| BBB  |   0         | 2012-04-10 08:44:19 |
| AAA  |   1         | 2012-04-10 09:44:19 |
| CCC  |   1         | 2012-04-11 09:48:19 |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I want to show unique date and count f_inserted where f_inserted = 1

In the folowing table I want the result as -

**result**

```
+-------------+------+
| date        |  cnt |
+-------------+------+
| 2012-04-10  |   2  | 
| 2012-04-11  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why isn't the `id` set as unique?

Comment: The id is name . No ID Sorry !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic [MySQL GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) query. The only tricky part is that your timestamp has a DATETIME, and you only want a date. Use the [DATE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to convert.

```
SELECT date(`timestamp`) as `date`, COUNT(*) from t1
WHERE f_inserted = 1
GROUP BY date(`timestamp`)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the exect result you wished for-

```
SELECT date(`timestamp`) as `date`,
COUNT(*) as cnt 
from table_name
WHERE f_inserted = 1
GROUP BY date(`timestamp`) 
order by cnt desc
```